# Android: What does ContentResolver.update() do excactly?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I want to use the method `ContentResolver.update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)`
I know how to use it, but I wonder what it does with the ContentValues. Does it overwrite ALL existing ContentValues, or does it only overwrite the given ContentValues?

So for example, these ContentValues exist:

```
A: abc
B: 123
C: 456
```

And the ContentValues in the `update()`method contain this:

```
A: asdf
C: 789
```

Then will the new ContentValues be: (only overwrite given values)

```
A: asdf
B: 123
C: 789
```

Or will it be: (overwrite all values)

```
A: asdf
C: 789
```

This is my code:

```
 contentResolver.update(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values, "_data=" + audioFilePath, null);
```

In which `values` contains the `ContentValues` that should be overwritten and `audioFilePath` contains the path to the audiofile (which is the value of `_data`).

Answer (score 3):

It will only overwrite the given ContentValues.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask you what your info-source is for this answer?

Answer (score 2):

[As per the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), all the ContentResolver.update() method does is call the update method of the ContentProvider that you've defined and identified by the URI you provide in the first argument.

So, to know exactly what's going on, you need to look at how you defined the update() method of the ContentProvider you are referencing.   [Take a look at the ContentProvider basics documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)   If you need help properly defining the update() method of your contentProvider, post your code here or ask a question specific to that.

Comment: For a typical `ContentProvider`, where `update()` on the provider routes directly to `update()` on a `SQLiteDatabase`, only the supplied columns will be replaced, and columns not referenced in the `ContentValues` will be ignored, because that is how a SQL `UPDATE` works. But, as @SBerg413 notes, there is no guarantee of this behavior; it is up to the `ContentProvider` implementation. Calling `update()` could not only replace skipped columns with `NULL`, but also post a Tweet and send a message to your Bluetooth-enabled dishwasher.

Comment: @SBerg413, I've updated my question with the code I'm using. Could you tell from that line if it overwrites all values or just the given?